# Eclipse is not running Java method: public void paint (Graphics g)

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm new to Eclipse, recently swapped from Bluej which ran my codes reliably. In Eclipse, it sometimes runs and sometimes just doesn't run the paint method and I'm not sure why. The same code was running this morning and now it decides to not run and I'm not sure what to do.

Main method:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import Asset.Paddle;
import Asset.Puck;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;



public class setup implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, Runnable {

    int width = 100;
    int height = 100;
    int scale = 8;


    public static setup setup;

    JFrame frame;

    JPanel main;

    Graphic graphic;

    Puck puck;

    Paddle paddle1,paddle2;

    boolean running, up = true, up2 = true;

    boolean menu = false, b1, b2, b3;

    int winSize;

    public setup() {                                            
        puck = new Puck((width*scale)/2,(width*scale)/2,20,20); 
        paddle1 = new Paddle(width*scale/8-20,height*scale/2,20,100);
        paddle2 = new Paddle(width*scale/8*7,height*scale/2,20,100);
        frame();
    }

    public void frame() {                                       //Frame setup
        frame = new JFrame("Pong");
        frame.setSize(width * scale,height * scale);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container c1 = frame.getContentPane();

        Dimension winSize = frame.getSize();
        System.out.println(winSize);

        graphic = new Graphic(puck,paddle1,paddle2);
        graphic.addKeyListener(this);
        graphic.addMouseListener(this);
        graphic.addMouseMotionListener(this);

        main = new JPanel();
        main.setLayout(new BorderLayout());          
        main.setSize(width * scale,height * scale);
        main.add(graphic,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        start();
        c1.add(main);
        graphic.requestFocus();
    }

    public void start() {                                       //running = true
        new Thread(this).start();
        running = true;
        menu = true;
        RENDER();   
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
    }

    public void run() {                                         //Game
        while(running == true) {                        
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(puck.getY() < 0 || puck.getY() > height * scale) {
                puck.reverseY();
            }

            paddle1.run();
            paddle2.run();
            puck.run();
            RENDER();   
        }
    }

    public void RENDER() {
        graphic.UPDATEPADDLE(paddle1,paddle2);
        graphic.UPDATEPUCK(puck);   
        graphic.repaint();
    }


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {                      
        if(evt.getKeyCode() == 81) {     // Q   
            paddle1.setYVel(-2);
            up = true;
        }   

        if(evt.getKeyCode() == 65) {    // A 
            paddle1.setYVel(2);
            up = false;
        }

        if(evt.getKeyCode() == 80) {     // P
            paddle2.setYVel(-2);
            up2 = true;
        }

        if(evt.getKeyCode() == 76) {
            paddle2.setYVel(2);
            up2 = false;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {                     
        if(evt.getKeyCode() == 81 && up  ) {     // Q       
            paddle1.setYVel(0);
        }   

        if(evt.getKeyCode() == 65 && !up) {     // A    
            paddle1.setYVel(0);
        }

        if(evt.getKeyCode() == 80 && up2) {     // P        
            paddle2.setYVel(0);
        }

        if(evt.getKeyCode() == 76 && !up2) {     // L
            paddle2.setYVel(0);
        }

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {}

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {    
//      if(e.getX() > 375 && e.getX() < 375 + 200  && e.getY() > 400 && e.getY() < 400 + 50) {
//          menu = false;
//          System.out.println("clicked");
//          graphic.UPDATEBUTTON(b1,b2,b3);
//          graphic.UPDATEMENU(menu);
//          start();
//          graphic.repaint();
//      }
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setup = new setup();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        if(e.getX() > 375 && e.getX() < 375 + 200  && e.getY() > 400 && e.getY() < 400 + 50) {
            b1 = true;
            graphic.UPDATEBUTTON(b1,b2,b3);
            graphic.repaint();
        }
            else {
                b1 = false;
                graphic.UPDATEBUTTON(b1,b2,b3);
                graphic.repaint();
            }

        }

    }
```

Paddle:

```
package Asset;

public class Paddle {
    double x, y, yVel, h, w;



    public Paddle(double xx, double yy, int width, int height) {
        x = xx;
        y = yy;
        h = height;
        w = width;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return (int)x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return (int)y;
    }

    public int getH() {
        return (int)h;
    }

    public int getW() {
        return (int)w;
    }

    public void setYVel(int yVelocity) {
        yVel = yVelocity;
    }

    public void run() {
     y += yVel;
     if(y < 0) {
         yVel = 0;
         y = 0;
     }



    }



}
```

Puck:

```
package Asset;

public class Puck {

    double x,y,w,h;
    double xVel = 0;
    double yVel = 3;

    public Puck(double xx, double yy,int width,int height) {
        x = xx;
        y = yy;
        w = width;
        h = height;
        x++;

    }   

    public void reverseY() {
        yVel *= -1;
    }

    public void reverseX() {
        xVel *= -1;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return (int)x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return (int)y;
    }

    public int getW() {
        return (int)w;
    }

    public int getH() {
        return (int)h;
    }

    public void run() {
        x += xVel;
        y += yVel;
    }

}
```

Setup:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import Asset.Paddle;
import Asset.Puck;

public class Graphic extends JPanel {  

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2273791975624707192L;

    Puck ppuck;
    Paddle ppaddle1,ppaddle2;
    boolean mmenu = true;
    boolean bb1,bb2,bb3;

    public Graphic(Puck puck,Paddle paddle1,Paddle paddle2) {  
        ppuck = puck;
        ppaddle1 = paddle1;
        ppaddle2 = paddle2;     
    }

    public void UPDATEMENU(boolean menu) {
        mmenu = menu;
    }

    public void UPDATEPADDLE(Paddle paddle1, Paddle paddle2) {
        ppaddle1 = paddle1;
        ppaddle2 = paddle2;
    }

    public void UPDATEPUCK(Puck puck) { 
        ppuck = puck;
    }

    public void UPDATEBUTTON(boolean b1,boolean b2, boolean b3) {
        bb1 = b1;
        bb2 = b2;
        bb3 = b3;
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);   
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

        if (mmenu) {    //menu 


            if(bb1) {
                g.setColor(Color.blue);
                g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 50)); 
                g.drawString("START", 390, 440);
            }
            else {
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 50)); 
                g.drawString("START", 390, 440);
            }

        }
        else {  
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillOval(ppuck.getX(), ppuck.getY(), ppuck.getW(), ppuck.getH());
        g.fillRect(ppaddle1.getX(), ppaddle1.getY(), ppaddle1.getW(), ppaddle1.getH());
        g.fillRect(ppaddle2.getX(), ppaddle2.getY(), ppaddle2.getW(), ppaddle2.getH());
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). BTW - the only class that overrides `paint(Graphics)` (the `Graphic` class which extends `JPanel`) should instead override `paintComponent(Graphics)` ..

Comment: Swing is not thread safe, you should not be trying to update the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, two "basic" problems...

One, if you modify the UI after the frame is visible, you must call `revalidate` and `repaint` too trigger a layout and paint pass.  A simpler solution, in your case, would be to call `setVisible` AFTER you've established the UI

```
public void frame() {                                       //Frame setup
    frame = new JFrame("Pong");
    frame.setSize(width * scale, height * scale);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    //frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container c1 = frame.getContentPane();

    //...

    start();
    c1.add(main);
    graphic.requestFocus();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Second...

This one's a little more complicated, but, you start your `Thread` and then update the state which it relies on to keep running

```
public void start() {                                       //running = true
    new Thread(this).start();
    running = true;
    menu = true;
    RENDER();
}
```

While very, very unlikely, it's possible that the thread will inspect the state before you change it ... or because of the way the memory model works, won't see the change.

Better to set it before hand...

```
public void start() {                                       //running = true
    running = true;
    new Thread(this).start();
    menu = true;
    RENDER();
}
```

You should also consider making it `volatile`

## Having said that...

You're going around it all the wrong way.

To start with, don't try and do all the rendering for all the states in the single view, instead, use seperate views to different states (such as the start screen and the game screen).

You could then make use of `CardLayout` or simply overlay the containers onto of each other when you want to switch between them.

Next, you should avoid using `KeyListener`, it's troublesome at the best of times.  Instead, make us of the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), then you won't need to post another question about why `KeyListener` has stopped working.

Next, Swing is single threaded and not thread safe.  This means you should not be performing blocking or long running operations within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread or updating the UI or a state the UI depends on from outside of it.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details.

The simple solution in this case is probably to use a Swing `Timer`, see [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

I would, personally, make the "game" panel responsible for setting up the input and rendering management, but that's me.